# Updating State with Variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to crack this particular nut where my state isn't updating.
I've got a function calling the NASA api through Axios which is working fine. Currently the `datePicked` state is empty by default which means the GET request defaults to the current date. I'm to adding functionality to generate a random date (function `onRandomDateClick`), which is all working fine.

Then I want to update the state of `datePicked` with the generated date, and then run the `onImageGet` function which holds the axios request.

**Initial State**

```
  class Photo extends Component {
    state = {
      apiUrl: 'XXXXXXXX',
      apiKey: 'XXXXXXXX',
      image: null,
      imgChecked: false,
      datePicked: ""
    };
```

**Generates random Date, logs variable and state. State currently displays blank. this.setState isn't working.**

```
    onRandomDateClick = (e) => {
      function randomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
      }
      let randomDateResult = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date())
      let datePicked = randomDateResult.toISOString().slice(0,10);
      this.setState({datePicked})
      console.log("variable is " + datePicked);
      console.log("state is " + this.state.datePicked);
      this.onImageGet();
    }
```

**Axios call with state here**

```
    onImageGet = e => {
      axios.get(`${this.state.apiUrl}?api_key=${this.state.apiKey}&date=${this.state.datePicked}`)
      //response always starts res.data
          .then(res => {
            const image = res.data;
            this.setState({ image })
          })
          this.setState({imgChecked: true})
    }


    render() {
      ...blah blah...
      return (
        <div className="photo">        

         ... blah blah blah ...
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: You haven't actually set the state. `this.setState({parameter: value})` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: Another approach is to use redux and and redux-axios-middleware for async operation.

Comment: js is async. you should do something like this. https://gist.github.com/nazrdogan/1167c9683a66f038516f527184b024c3

Comment: @KenoClayton I was under the impression that if the var name and the state were the same it's possible to do it like this? Is that incorrect?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, I've never seen that implementation, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: Are you sure `onRandomDateClick` is bound to this? I suppose it is not, so this.setState does not work as you exect. Please provide your full code, expecially where `onRandomDateClick` is called...

Comment: @NazırDogan Thanks very much!

Comment: @RobHern is it work ? I will post as an answer.

Comment: It did yes! Please do I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js is working async for http call. for React `setState` is async.you should do something like this.

```js
onRandomDateClick = (e) => {
      function randomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
      }
      let randomDateResult = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date())
      let datePicked = randomDateResult.toISOString().slice(0,10);
      this.setState({datePicked},() => {
        this.onImageGet();
      })
    }
    
    onImageGet = e => {
      axios.get(`${this.state.apiUrl}?api_key=${this.state.apiKey}&date=${this.state.datePicked}`)
      //response always starts res.data
          .then(res => {
            const image = res.data;
            this.setState({ image, imgChecked: true })

          })
        
    }
    render() {
      ...blah blah...
      return (
        <div className="photo">        

         ... blah blah blah ...
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is not JS that is async. It is that the `setState` is async.

Comment: I mean for http call. maybe its misleading. I will edit :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setState` is asynchronous so when you call `onImageGet` right after setting the state, the state has not yet been updated and you access the previous one.

You could use the callback method that `setState` supports which is called once the state has been updated.

```
this.setState({datePicked}, this.onImageGet)
```

or a more common pattern would be to check for relevant changes in the `componentDidUpdate` and call the `this.onImageGet` there.

```js
  class Photo extends Component {
    state = {
      apiUrl: 'XXXXXXXX',
      apiKey: 'XXXXXXXX',
      image: null,
      imgChecked: false,
      datePicked: ""
    };


    onRandomDateClick = (e) => {
      function randomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
      }
      let randomDateResult = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date())
      let datePicked = randomDateResult.toISOString().slice(0,10);
      this.setState({datePicked})
      console.log("variable is " + datePicked);
      console.log("state is " + this.state.datePicked);
    }

    onImageGet = e => {
      axios.get(`${this.state.apiUrl}?api_key=${this.state.apiKey}&date=${this.state.datePicked}`)
      //response always starts res.data
          .then(res => {
            const image = res.data;
            this.setState({ image })
          })
          this.setState({imgChecked: true})
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      if (prevState.datePicked !== this.state.datePicked){
        this.onImageGet();
      }
    }

    render() {
      ...blah blah...
      return (
        <div className="photo">        
         ... blah blah blah ...
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's really useful to see different implementations of the solution.